# Uglify module names with r.js optimizer

Tags: javascript, requirejs, obfuscation

For further uglification of a script bundle that was optimized by requirejs' r.js optimizer, it makes sense to obfuscate/anonymize the module names inside that package. Unfortunately, browsing through the documentation of r.js, I did not find a way to enable this. Is this possible?

An example of what I mean
module "ProductsController" could be "module1", module "BillingRepository" could be "module17" and so on. It would make it harder to make sense of the uglified code.

Comment: what about to use Grunt or Gult task to copy module files to special folder, rename them with some algorithm and run buld from this special folder?

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't be enough to rename the files as the modules inside those files reference each other and those references would then be broken. It would be possible (I guess) to find all module names in the concat'ed file and replace those in the whole bundle at once, but I hoped that r.js could already do that :)